# When I create a flutter-plugin project,I can't find flutter

Tags: flutter

[image]
So I add flutter as library like this:

[image]

[image]

Should I delete these when I finished my plugin?

Comment: https://flutter.io/docs/get-started/install

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are free (and actually there's nothing wrong about it) to add the flutter lib to your `build.gradle`. However keep a few things in mind:

- I **strongly** advise you to add that folder (*libs.android-arm*) to your .gitignore (you don't want to upload or keep track of it).
- You **must** remove/comment that line otherwise it won't build in other machines since that will reference a lib/path that doesn't exist.